# How to create for IntentIntegrator in Android with zXing

Tags: android, zxing

I want to create a object for `IntentIntegrator` in Android.

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(ZBarReaderActivity.this);
```

Here `ZBarReaderActivity` is my `Activity` class.

Thanks in Advance,

Please help me.

IntentIntegrator is class from com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator package.

which is used for identify Qr Code content is Telephone Number, WebSite, WebUrl.

Comment: can u elaborate your question more

Answer (score 3):

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);  /* "this" is enough */
```

for further information, watch this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mVkaua4Lcvo
it's explained in german, but you can see the code and how they create a object for IntentIntegrator.

p.s: and you have to explain it in greater detail otherwise you cannot get an answer for your question.

Comment: PS he might need "ZBarActivity.this" if the invocation is inside an anonymous inner class, like a click handler.

Comment: IntentIntegrator has a private constructor. So how can you create an instance from it?

Answer (score 3):

This is the intentintegrator I've used

**IntentIntegrator.java**

```
/*
 * Copyright 2009 ZXing authors
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.your.package.name;

import com.your.package.name.IntentIntegrator;
import com.your.package.name.IntentResult;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

/**
 * <p>A utility class which helps ease integration with Barcode Scanner via {@link Intent}s. This is a simple
 * way to invoke barcode scanning and receive the result, without any need to integrate, modify, or learn the
 * project's source code.</p>
 *
 * <h2>Initiating a barcode scan</h2>
 *
 * <p>Integration is essentially as easy as calling {@link #initiateScan(Activity)} and waiting
 * for the result in your app.</p>
 *
 * <p>It does require that the Barcode Scanner application is installed. The
 * {@link #initiateScan(Activity)} method will prompt the user to download the application, if needed.</p>
 *
 * <p>There are a few steps to using this integration. First, your {@link Activity} must implement
 * the method {@link Activity#onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)} and include a line of code like this:</p>
 *
 * <p>{@code
 * public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
 *   IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
 *   if (scanResult != null) {
 *     // handle scan result
 *   }
 *   // else continue with any other code you need in the method
 *   ...
 * }
 * }</p>
 *
 * <p>This is where you will handle a scan result.
 * Second, just call this in response to a user action somewhere to begin the scan process:</p>
 *
 * <p>{@code IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(yourActivity);}</p>
 *
 * <p>You can use {@link #initiateScan(Activity, CharSequence, CharSequence, CharSequence, CharSequence)} or
 * {@link #initiateScan(Activity, int, int, int, int)} to customize the download prompt with
 * different text labels.</p>
 *
 * <p>Note that {@link #initiateScan(Activity)} returns an {@link AlertDialog} which is non-null if the
 * user was prompted to download the application. This lets the calling app potentially manage the dialog.
 * In particular, ideally, the app dismisses the dialog if it's still active in its {@link Activity#onPause()}
 * method.</p>
 *
 * <h2>Sharing text via barcode</h2>
 *
 * <p>To share text, encoded as a QR Code on-screen, similarly, see {@link #shareText(Activity, CharSequence)}.</p>
 *
 * <p>Some code, particularly download integration, was contributed from the Anobiit application.</p>
 *
 * @author Sean Owen
 * @author Fred Lin
 * @author Isaac Potoczny-Jones
 * @author Brad Drehmer
 */
public final class IntentIntegrator {

  public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0x0ba7c0de; // get it?

  public static final String DEFAULT_TITLE = "Install Barcode Scanner?";
  public static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE =
      "This application requires Barcode Scanner. Would you like to install it?";
  public static final String DEFAULT_YES = "Yes";
  public static final String DEFAULT_NO = "No";

  // supported barcode formats
  public static final String PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES = "UPC_A,UPC_E,EAN_8,EAN_13";
  public static final String ONE_D_CODE_TYPES = PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES + ",CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128";
  public static final String QR_CODE_TYPES = "QR_CODE";
  public static final String ALL_CODE_TYPES = null;

  private IntentIntegrator() {
  }

  /**
   * See {@link #initiateScan(Activity, CharSequence, CharSequence, CharSequence, CharSequence)} --
   * same, but uses default English labels.
   */
  public static AlertDialog initiateScan(Activity activity) {
    return initiateScan(activity, DEFAULT_TITLE, DEFAULT_MESSAGE, DEFAULT_YES, DEFAULT_NO);
  }

  /**
   * See {@link #initiateScan(Activity, CharSequence, CharSequence, CharSequence, CharSequence)} --
   * same, but takes string IDs which refer
   * to the {@link Activity}'s resource bundle entries.
   */
  public static AlertDialog initiateScan(Activity activity,
                                         int stringTitle,
                                         int stringMessage,
                                         int stringButtonYes,
                                         int stringButtonNo) {
    return initiateScan(activity,
                        activity.getString(stringTitle),
                        activity.getString(stringMessage),
                        activity.getString(stringButtonYes),
                        activity.getString(stringButtonNo));
  }

  /**
   * See {@link #initiateScan(Activity, CharSequence, CharSequence, CharSequence, CharSequence, CharSequence)} --
   * same, but scans for all supported barcode types.
   * @param stringTitle title of dialog prompting user to download Barcode Scanner
   * @param stringMessage text of dialog prompting user to download Barcode Scanner
   * @param stringButtonYes text of button user clicks when agreeing to download
   *  Barcode Scanner (e.g. "Yes")
   * @param stringButtonNo text of button user clicks when declining to download
   *  Barcode Scanner (e.g. "No")
   * @return an {@link AlertDialog} if the user was prompted to download the app,
   *  null otherwise
   */
  public static AlertDialog initiateScan(Activity activity,
                                         CharSequence stringTitle,
                                         CharSequence stringMessage,
                                         CharSequence stringButtonYes,
                                         CharSequence stringButtonNo) {

    return initiateScan(activity,
                        stringTitle,
                        stringMessage,
                        stringButtonYes,
                        stringButtonNo,
                        ALL_CODE_TYPES);
  }

  /**
   * Invokes scanning.
   *
   * @param stringTitle title of dialog prompting user to download Barcode Scanner
   * @param stringMessage text of dialog prompting user to download Barcode Scanner
   * @param stringButtonYes text of button user clicks when agreeing to download
   *  Barcode Scanner (e.g. "Yes")
   * @param stringButtonNo text of button user clicks when declining to download
   *  Barcode Scanner (e.g. "No")
   * @param stringDesiredBarcodeFormats a comma separated list of codes you would
   *  like to scan for.
   * @return an {@link AlertDialog} if the user was prompted to download the app,
   *  null otherwise
   * @throws InterruptedException if timeout expires before a scan completes
   */
  public static AlertDialog initiateScan(Activity activity,
                                         CharSequence stringTitle,
                                         CharSequence stringMessage,
                                         CharSequence stringButtonYes,
                                         CharSequence stringButtonNo,
                                         CharSequence stringDesiredBarcodeFormats) {
    Intent intentScan = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intentScan.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

    // check which types of codes to scan for
    if (stringDesiredBarcodeFormats != null) {
      // set the desired barcode types
      intentScan.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", stringDesiredBarcodeFormats);
    }

    try {
      activity.startActivityForResult(intentScan, REQUEST_CODE);
      return null;
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
      return showDownloadDialog(activity, stringTitle, stringMessage, stringButtonYes, stringButtonNo);
    }
  }

  private static AlertDialog showDownloadDialog(final Activity activity,
                                                CharSequence stringTitle,
                                                CharSequence stringMessage,
                                                CharSequence stringButtonYes,
                                                CharSequence stringButtonNo) {
    AlertDialog.Builder downloadDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    downloadDialog.setTitle(stringTitle);
    downloadDialog.setMessage(stringMessage);
    downloadDialog.setPositiveButton(stringButtonYes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:com.google.zxing.client.android");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
      }
    });
    downloadDialog.setNegativeButton(stringButtonNo, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {}
    });
    return downloadDialog.show();
  }


  /**
   * <p>Call this from your {@link Activity}'s
   * {@link Activity#onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)} method.</p>
   *
   * @return null if the event handled here was not related to {@link IntentIntegrator}, or
   *  else an {@link IntentResult} containing the result of the scan. If the user cancelled scanning,
   *  the fields will be null.
   */
  public static IntentResult parseActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
        String formatName = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
        return new IntentResult(contents, formatName);
      } else {
        return new IntentResult(null, null);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  /**
   * See {@link #shareText(Activity, CharSequence, CharSequence, CharSequence, CharSequence, CharSequence)} --
   * same, but uses default English labels.
   */
  public static void shareText(Activity activity, CharSequence text) {
    shareText(activity, text, DEFAULT_TITLE, DEFAULT_MESSAGE, DEFAULT_YES, DEFAULT_NO);
  }

  /**
   * See {@link #shareText(Activity, CharSequence, CharSequence, CharSequence, CharSequence, CharSequence)} --
   * same, but takes string IDs which refer to the {@link Activity}'s resource bundle entries.
   */
  public static void shareText(Activity activity,
                               CharSequence text,
                               int stringTitle,
                               int stringMessage,
                               int stringButtonYes,
                               int stringButtonNo) {
    shareText(activity,
              text,
              activity.getString(stringTitle),
              activity.getString(stringMessage),
              activity.getString(stringButtonYes),
              activity.getString(stringButtonNo));
  }

  /**
   * Shares the given text by encoding it as a barcode, such that another user can
   * scan the text off the screen of the device.
   *
   * @param text the text string to encode as a barcode
   * @param stringTitle title of dialog prompting user to download Barcode Scanner
   * @param stringMessage text of dialog prompting user to download Barcode Scanner
   * @param stringButtonYes text of button user clicks when agreeing to download
   *  Barcode Scanner (e.g. "Yes")
   * @param stringButtonNo text of button user clicks when declining to download
   *  Barcode Scanner (e.g. "No")
   */
  public static void shareText(Activity activity,
                               CharSequence text,
                               CharSequence stringTitle,
                               CharSequence stringMessage,
                               CharSequence stringButtonYes,
                               CharSequence stringButtonNo) {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE");
    intent.putExtra("ENCODE_TYPE", "TEXT_TYPE");
    intent.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA", text);
    try {
      activity.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
      showDownloadDialog(activity, stringTitle, stringMessage, stringButtonYes, stringButtonNo);
    }
  }

}
```

**IntentResult.java**

```
/*
 * Copyright 2009 ZXing authors
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.your.package.name;

import com.your.package.name.IntentIntegrator;

/**
 * <p>Encapsulates the result of a barcode scan invoked through {@link IntentIntegrator}.</p>
 *
 * @author Sean Owen
 */
public final class IntentResult {

  private final String contents;
  private final String formatName;

  IntentResult(String contents, String formatName) {
    this.contents = contents;
    this.formatName = formatName;
  }

  /**
   * @return raw content of barcode
   */
  public String getContents() {
    return contents;
  }

  /**
   * @return name of format, like "QR_CODE", "UPC_A". See <code>BarcodeFormat</code> for more format names.
   */
  public String getFormatName() {
    return formatName;
  }    
}
```

And then to use it

```
private void someFunction()
    {
        IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(this);
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch(requestCode) {
            case IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE: 
            {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                }
                else 
                    {                   
                        IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                        String UPCScanned = scanResult.getContents();
                    }
            break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not just use the one in the project?

Comment: That is the one from the project..as far as I can remember the only difference for me was I wanted it to only scan UPC-A

Comment: You can already restrict the scan format with the existing IntentIntegrator

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your dependencies

```
 implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.1.0'
```